Obtaining a static property from a Type
I currently have this code:
private static DiscordIntents GetModuleIntents(Type event_module)
{
    return (DiscordIntents)event_module.InvokeMember(
        "RequiredIntents",
        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetProperty,
        null,
        null,
        null
    );
}

This works, but I was wondering if it possible to take advantage of the fact the the type implements IEventHandler to avoid InvokeMember?
To give an idea about how it's used:
public interface IEventHandler
{
    public static abstract DiscordIntents RequiredIntents { get; }
}

class EventHandler(...) : IEventHandler, ...
{
    public static Discord​Intents RequiredIntents { get; } = ...;

    ...
}

// Classes that implement `IEventHandler`.
IEnumerable<Type> event_modules =
[
    typeof(EventHandler),
    ...
];

var intents = ...;

foreach (var event_module in event_modules)
    intents |= GetModuleIntents(event_module);

DiscordClientBuilder builder = DiscordClientBuilder.CreateDefault(token, intents);


You don't show any code that uses anything other than RequiredIntents from the elements of event_modules.
If this is really the case, then you could use a IEnumerable<Func<DiscordIntents>> rather than IEnumerable<Type>:
static IEnumerable<Func<DiscordIntents>> modules()
{
    return new List<Func<DiscordIntents>> {
        () => EventHandler.RequiredIntents
    };
}

Then you can just do:
DiscordIntents intents = 0;

foreach (var intent in modules())
{
    intents |= intent();
}

Obviously this will only work if you don't need anything else from the IEventHandler types.

Thanks, but it's not the only user. They are used twice more later. Primarily, they are provided to the library communicating with Discord, which will instantiate them and dispatch events to them (using Dependency Injection). But I need to tell the library which groups of events it requires from Discord (the "intents") up front. Without these, Discord won't send the events as a traffic-reduction measure.
